# Autofac Register Different Implementation To Different Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I have an **ITestService** interface. **TestService1** and **TestService2** implements ITestService. What I want is to use **TestService1** for **Controller1** and **TestService2** for **Controller2**. How to do that in Autofac ?

I am using ASP.NET MVC4.

**I tried this one but it didnt worked**

```
builder.RegisterType<Controller1>().WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ITestService>("TestService1")).InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<Controller2>().WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ITestService>("TestService2")).InstancePerDependency();
```

I also tried this one, no success

```
    builder.RegisterType<TestService1>().Named<ITestService>("TestService1").As<ICategoryService>();
    builder.RegisterType<TestService2>().Named<ICategoryService>("TestService2").As<ICategoryService>();

    builder.RegisterType<Nop.Web.Controllers.Controller1>().WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ITestService>("TestService1"));
    builder.RegisterType<Nop.Admin.Controllers.Controller2>().WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ITestService>("TestService2"));
```

Comment: Your second example should work, what error message do you get? The only oddity in your sample that you sometimes write `ITestService` sometimes `ICategoryService` but I guess this is just a typo in your example...

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned the names "TestService1" and "TestService2"? e.g.

```
builder.RegisterType<TestService1>().As<ITestService1>().Named("TestService1");
builder.RegisterType<TestService2>().As<ITestService2>().Named("TestService2");
```

Comment: I get a compile time error when I try you write

Service.ExtendedCategoryService,Autofac.Builder.ConcreteReflectionActivatorData,Autofac.Builder.SingleRegistrationStyle>.Named<TService>(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.